# Expression Expected Error in mY vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I have folowing error in my code please anyone tell me how to remove it from code
here is my code

```
Protected Sub addListItems()

        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim past As DateTime = now.AddDays(-20)
        Dim dates As New List(Of DateTime)()
        Dim curDate As DateTime = now
        While curDate > past
            dates.Add(curDate)
            curDate = curDate.AddDays(-1)
        End While
        'Add Date Values TO DPR Jhang
        ddlTrnDte.Attributes("onchange") = "window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptestdpr&report=DPR_SEASON_20102011_W&P_1='+ this.value, 'mywindow4');"
        ddlTrnDte.Attributes("onclick") = "return sel_veh_onclick();"
        ddlTrnDte.Items.Clear()
        ddlTrnDte.Items.Add(New ListItem("Please Select", ""))
    ddlTrnDte.Items.AddRange(dates.ConvertAll(Function(dt) New ListItem(dt.ToString("dd-MMM"), dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))).ToArray())


    End Sub
```

The error is in last line on function "Expression Expected"

```
ConvertAll(Function(dt)
```

Anyone tell me what is wrong with this code

Comment: Anyone please answer to the question